# Having the correct value of 'this' in JS

Tags: javascript, this

I have two Javascript "objects" similar to so....

```
var Object2 = new (function() {
    this.FetchData = function(callback) {
        // do some stuff
        callback(data);
    };
});

var Object1 = new (function() {

    this.DisplayStuff = function() {

    };

    this.LoadData = function() {
        Object2.FetchData(this.OnData);
    };

    this.OnData = function(data) {
        // this == window
        this.DisplayStuff();   // doesn't work
    };

});
```

When Object1 receives the callback to OnData, the value of "this" is set to window.  **Is there any way I can get around this so that the value of "this" inside of OnData will be the instance of Object1** instead of window?

Comment: Who does call Object1.OnData? Did you attach it to an event? Could you show the code of how you attached it to an event?

Comment: Where does Object 2 call Object 1? Is the callback one of the methods on Object 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way of doing it is storing a reference to *this* in a variable, then using the [*call()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method:

```
this.LoadData = function() {
    var self = this;
    Object2.FetchData(function () { self.OnData.call(self) });
};
```

If you're doing this a lot, you might want to consider using the *.bind()* method on the function prototype in ECMAScript 5th edition. This method can be implemented where unsupported:

```
// From Prototype.js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}
```

And the resulting function call:

```
this.LoadData = function() {
    Object2.FetchData(this.OnData.bind(this));
};
```

[PrototypeJS - *bind()*](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind)

Comment: Slick!  Something like this is what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 5):

A technique commonly used in frameworks is to let the caller decide on what the `this` context should be for the callback function. So the `FetchData` function looks like (thanks to @Andy for telling me about the default scope when context is null or undefined - it is the global object),

```
this.FetchData = function(callback, context) {
    callback.call(context, data);
};
```

When calling `FetchData`, pass `Object1` as the context for the callback,

```
Object2.FetchData(this.OnData, this);
```

---

Another option is to bind the `OnData` function with `Object1` using [Function.prototype.bind](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com+Function.prototype.bind&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

```
Object2.FetchData(this.onData.bind(this));
```

Comment: I wish I could pick two answers.  This is a great response.

Comment: No need for `context || window`, if context is *undefined* or *null* it will already default to the global object, which is *window* in the case of webpages.

Comment: @Andy - thanks for pointing our the default behavior for unspecified context. thanks @T. Stone - glad you liked it

Answer (score 0):

The basic solution is to force context on the callback with `apply`. (Or `call`. The difference is how parameters are passed. Either an array or 'normally') See the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For a callback, you're stuck with 'this' being the window (usually). However, you could add a member to Object1 that points to itself (a lot of times it's gets call 'self', i.e. "var self = this;"), and then use that, i.e. self.DisplayStuff().

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity of "this" is really annoying to me with javascript. So I just avoid "this" as much as possible. I do it this way:

```
var Object2 = (function() { // no need for a "new" keyword any more

    var self = {}; // instead of the auto-supplied "this", create my own "self"

    self.FetchData = function(callback) {
        // do some stuff
        callback(data);
    };
    return self; // don't forget to return "self"
});

var Object1 = (function() {

    var self = {}; // instead of the auto-supplied "this", create my own "self"

    self.DisplayStuff = function() {

    };

    self.LoadData = function() {
        Object2.FetchData(this.OnData);
    };

    self.OnData = function(data) {
        self.DisplayStuff();
    };

    return self; // don't forget to return "self"

});
```

You lose the ability to use Object.prototype with this technique, you lose the ability to test using "instanceof", but you never have to think about what "this" is.

Comment: Why not just set self to this? Then you don't lose those abilities.

Comment: That works totally fine too. I think I starting doing it this way because I was feeling angry at "this" and was excited about the idea of banishing it.

Comment: Actually, that's not true. I've been experimenting with Crockford's "Parasitic Inheritance" approach, which eschews "this". http://blog.higher-order.net/2008/02/21/javascript-parasitic-inheritance-power-constructors-and-instanceof/