# javascript setInterval on an object's function only calls 2x

Tags: javascript

```
var focus = true;

function z() {
    this.t = 0;
    this.p = function (t) {
        if (focus == true) {
            this.t = t;
            alert(this.t);

        }

    }
}
var zp = new z();
setTimeout('zp.p(0)', 100);
window.setInterval('zp.p(1)', 2000);
var ftimer = setTimeout('focus=false', 2000);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(ftimer);
    focus = true;
    ftimer = setTimeout('focus=false', 2000);
}, false);
```

I have this code. but for some reason it only alerts twice even with continuous mouse movements. I have been working at this and investigating in firebug and focus is true when I am moving my mouse. I have been trying to figure out what is going on.. even if I do this:

```
function z() {
    this.t = 0;
    this.p = function (t) {
        if (focus == true) {
            this.t = t;

        }
        alert(this.t);

    }
}
```

It still only alerts twice.

I have tried using a looping setTimeout function too but that doesnt work either. It is driving me crazy.

Comment: It seems to alert continuously for me.

Comment: What are you trying to do anyways? It always alerts `1` to me, doesn't seem to have any particular use. Also using strings in `setTimeout` makes use of `eval` which is evil, use anonymous functions in this case. You should either tell us what the expected effect of this is, or refactor your code to indicate it. Because who the hell knows what a `z` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good that you found your bug.

I would write your code using a bit more functions-as-first-class-objects and less `eval` logic:

```
var focus = true;
function z() {
    var that = this; // we won't always have the correct value of "this"
    this.focus = true;
    this.t = 0;
    this.p = function (t) {
        if (that.focus == true) {
            that.t = t;
            alert(t);
        }
    }
    this.fade = ( function(obj){ return function(){ obj.focus = false; } } )(this); // Using self-invokation
}
var zp = new z();
setTimeout(zp.p, 100, 0);
window.setInterval(zp.p, 2000, 1);
var ftimer = setTimeout(zp.fade, 2000);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    clearTimeout(ftimer);
    zp.focus = true;
    ftimer = setTimeout(zp.fade, 2000);
}, false);
```

I used a [self-invoking function](http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/) on line 10: `( function(obj){ return function(){...} })(this);`, and [set `this` to a different variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610596/having-the-correct-value-of-this-in-js).

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was just related to firefox and that firefox choked on a line of code so that is why it wouldn't run. So I fixed that and now everything is all good.

Comment: Your code is certainly sub-optimal, and if you say what you are *actually* trying to do, people can (and probably will) come up with a better version.